# Apply coupon code only to non discounted products

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes

I need to make a coupon code which should be applied only to non-discounted products and certain categories. In Cart price rules->Actions I tried the following conditions:

> If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
>
> Special Price  is  0
> Category is not one of  727, 777, 1379, 1380, 778, 111...

However, the coupon is getting applied to discounted products also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento does not have the feature like check the product catalogue discount on the cart items.

Magento ***does not calculate Catalogue discount*** like ***Catalog Price rules,Special Price rules, Tier price*** on cart price rules.

As per as,magento architecture ,a **product price** during **add to cart** time depends on  **Final Price field of products** which is depends on `Catalog Price rules, Special Price rules, Tier price`.

The final price does not calculate as cart item element,So you cannot do like that what you want.

Comment: So we cannot make a cart price rule which can only be applied to non-discounted products in any way?

Comment: Maybe can, have some tricky way but not sure how much it will effect. Create an attribute `yes/no`   product attributes  and  using a cronjob  make this attribute value to **yes if you have produced has some  catalog price discount*** you have  to logic ` product->getPrice() ->$product->getFinalPrice() >0 ` and after that enable this  attribute for shopping cart rules conditon. But this logic has issue might be in configurable,grouped,bundle and if tier price is set for customer group wise

Answer (score 0):

This should work for applying cart rule only to products with no special price:

1. Set Special Price attribute to be used in the cart rules
2. Create a new cart rule and in it's "Actions" tab set "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions" to:

> If ALL  of these conditions are FALSE :  Special Price  greater than
> 0

3. You could also set "Discard subsequent rules" to YES

In my tests this worked.