# how to exclude special prices and multiple purchase discount from coupon code discounts

Tags: discount, coupon-codes

I want to create a discount code which will allow x% discount on the customers basket but I want to exclude items that are already have a discount applied (Special Price) but also want to exclude items which have a discount applied when 2 or more have been purchased.

See the attached image of my current conditions and actions we have setup
[image: Condition and actions setup]

Comment: Check the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/269616/4564 You cannot use Special   price on Coupon conditions

Comment: the link is nothing to do with what I have asked for!

Comment: You want to exclude those products which have a special price. This condition not possible to implement .See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/269376/4564  
 is right link.Mistakenly I have shared the wrong link previously